# Contribution vs Contributions

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-choice

> The main *contributions* of this book are as follows.
>
> The main *contribution* of this book is as follows.

In the above context, which one between *contributions* or *contribution* is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but depends on how many "Contributions" are you going to mention. If it is only one then use the singular, if more than one then use the plural.